# Python - KeyError

Tags: mysql, python

Alguem pode me ajudar !

Estou fazendo a leitura de um arquivo csv e em seguinda faço um INSERT no banco MySQL, mas recebo o seguinte erro

**KeyError: 'id'**

Ja verifiquei o arquivo CSV varias vezes, o arquivo tem todas as colunas e exatamente com o mesmo nome..

[image: arquivo csv]

```
import csv
import pymysql

# importa o arquivo de acesso ao banco
from config import config

# faz a conexão com o banco de dados
cnx = pymysql.connect(**config, charset='utf8')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

# ler o arquivo csv
input_file = csv.DictReader(open("teste.csv", encoding='utf-8'))

# importa o arquivo csv no banco de dados
for row in input_file:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO teste.tabela (id,nome) \
                    VALUES (%s,%s)",(row['id'],row['nome']))
    print("Importando Linhas")
    cnx.commit()
```

Comment: Poderia acrescentar na pergunta algumas linhas do arquivo csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque um "print" dentro do `for` e você vai entender imediatamente o que está acontecendo.

Só com os dados que você colocou não dá pra afirmar com certeza, mas se você gravou o CSV de um Microsoft Excel em português, o separador vai ser o caractér `;`, por exemplo, em vez de  `,` - o módulo csv do Python não usa qualquer tipo de inferência para adivinhar qual é o separador.

(Você também pode verificar isso abrindo seu arquivo CSV no editor de programação, em vez de abrir sempre no programa de planilha (i.e. Excel, LibreOffice, GoogleSheets) - se for o caso, como parece, do separador não ser uma vírgula, é só informar isso na criação do DictReader:

```
input_file = csv.DictReader(open("teste.csv", encoding='utf-8'), delimiter=';')
```